# What is the Basis of the Kernel and the Image

Tags: linear-algebra

$R^4 \to R^3$ where $ f(x,y,z,w) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}2x + z -w\\x +w\\x +z-2w\end{array}\right]$

I started with matrix  $ A = $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}2 & 0 & 1 & -1\\1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1 &-2\end{array}\right]$

and set it to 0 and the result $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & -3 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 &0 &0\end{array}\right]$

The basis of the kernel or $\ker(F)$ is $\Biggl\{\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\\0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}-1\\0\\3\\1\end{array}\right)\Biggl\} $

With dim = 2

and the basis of the image is $\Biggl\{\left(\begin{array}{c}2\\1\\1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\1\end{array}\right)\Biggl\} $
With Dim = 2

Did I miss up somewhere ?

Comment: No, it looks correct

Comment: It is correct, but you may take $(0, 1 ,-1)$ for the first vector of the image (would be simpler).

Comment: @Bernard Or also $(1,1,0)$ if I'm not wrong, but I don't think those are relevant simplifications.

Comment: Of course, this depends on what comes afterwards, butI tend to think it is always sound to make things as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are right indeed we can check that

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}2 & 0 & 1 & -1\\1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1 &-2\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\\0\end{array}\right]=\vec 0$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}2 & 0 & 1 & -1\\1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1 &-2\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}-1\\0\\3\\1\end{array}\right]=\vec 0$$

and by RREF first and third colum of the original matrix are linearly independent.